# How can i find for every pixel on the screen which object it belongs to?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapping, shader

Each frame unity generate an image. I want that it will also create an additional arrays of int's and every time it decide to write a new color on the generated image it will write the id of the object on the correspond place in the array of int's.

In OpenGL I know that it’s pretty common and I found a lot of tutorials for this kind of things, basically based on the depth map you decide which id should be written at each pixel of the helper array. but in unity i using a given Shader and i didn't find a proper way to do just that. i think there should be any build in functions for this kind of common problem.

my goal is to know for every pixel on the screen which object it belongs to.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you extend the first section a bit? I don't really understand what your goal is. You want to know for every pixel on the screen which object it belongs to?

Comment: yes, that is my goal.

Comment: you can raycast from the camera into each pixel but that's going to be very expensive (not for realtime appliactions). alternatively you could render a second pass with different (unlit color?) materials assigned

Answer (score 0):

In forward rendering if you don't use it for another purpose you could store the ID into the alpha channel of the back buffer (and it would only be valid for opaque objects), up to 256 IDs without HDR. In deferred you could edit the unused channel of the gbuffer potentially.

This is if you want to minimize overhead, otherwise you could have a more generic system that re-renders specific objects into a texture in screenspace, whith a very simple shader that just outputs ID, into whatever format you need, using command buffers.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to make a **custom shader** that renders the default textures and colors to the mainCamera and renders an ID color to a renderTexture trough another camera.

Here's an example of how it works [Implementing Watering in my Farming Game!](https://youtu.be/-4_ucqmAbNk)